# how to skip backslash followed by integer?

Tags: python, regex

i have regex https://regex101.com/r/2H5ew6/1

```
(\!|\@)(1) 

Hello!1 World
```

and i wanna get first mark (!|@) and change the number `1` to another number `2`
I did

```
{\1}2_
\1\\2_
```

but it adds extra text and i just wanna change the number

i expect result to be

```
Hello!2_World
```

and ifusing @ to be

```
Hello@2_World
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match and capture either `!` or `@` in a named capture group, here called `char`, if followed by one or more digits and a whitespace:

```
(?P<char>[!@])\d+\s
```

Substitute with the named capture, `\g<char>` followed by `2_`:

```
\g<char>2_
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WBo3Gi/1)

If you only want the substitution if there's a `1` following either `!` or `@`, replace `\d+` with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

In your substitution you need to change the `{\1}2_` to just `2_`.

```
string = "Hello!1 World"
pattern = "(\!|\@)(1)"
replacement = "2_"
result = re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)
```

Comment: i lose `!` after

Answer (score 1):

Why not: `string.replace('!1 ', '!2_').replace('@1 ', '@2_')` ?

```
>>> string = "Hello!1 World"
>>> repl = lambda s: s.replace('!1 ', '!2_').replace('@1 ', '@2_')
>>> string2 = repl(string)
>>> string2
'Hello!2_World'
>>> string = "Hello!12 World"
>>> string2 = repl(string)
>>> string2
'Hello!12 World'
```

Answer (score 0):

The replacement for you pattern should be `\g<1>2_`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/63Mmau/1)

You could also shorten your pattern to a single capture with a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[!@]` and a match and use the same replacement as above.

`([!@])1`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g4d4TZ/1)

Or with a lookbehind assertion without any groups and replace with `2_`

`(?<=[!@])1`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tp05tO/1)